# An element not belong to any proper prime ideal in given commutative ring with 1.

Tags: abstract-algebra

It may be a dumb question but. Assume $R$ be a commutative ring with unity 1. Let $x\in R$ given.

If $x$ is invertible I know that it cannot be in any proper ideal. If $x$ is not invertible can I say that there should be at least one prime ideal contains that. Of course I am talking about nontrivial cases, such as R being a field etc.

I tried to construct an ideal contains it but even the set $\{x\in R| \text{x is non invertible}\}$ is not an ideal iff $R$ is not local ring.

Comment: Are you comfortable with the use of Zorn's lemma?

Comment: Yes, At least I can follow it.

Comment: By the way can we say the exact statement for prime but non maxımal ideals so is every non invertible element contains in a prime but non maximal ideal.

Comment: Every ideal is contained in a maximal ideal (Zorn), so if $x\in R$ is not a unit, then $(x)\subseteq \mathfrak{m}$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: yes true, I also remembered that after paul blart math cop's comment then what do you think about non maximal primes?

Comment: You can take for instance $2 \in \mathbb Z$. This is not a unit but $(2)$ is a maximal ideal, so in particular $2$ cannot be contained in any non-maximal prime ideals. In fact, the only non-maximal prime ideal in $\mathbb Z$. There are even rings (which we refer to as having dimension 0) in which all primes are maximal.

Comment: @Jale'dejaled:  I answered your question.   ***Cheers!***

Answer (score 1):

With our OP Jale'de jaled we take $R$ to be a unital commutative ring with unit $1$.

Then if

$x \in R \tag 1$

is invertible, and

$J \subset R \tag 2$

is an ideal of $R$ with

$x \in J, \tag 3$

we have

$1 = x^{-1}x \in J \tag 4$

so for any

$y \in R \tag 5$

it follows that

$y = y \cdot 1 \in J \tag 6$

which implies

$R \subset J; \tag 7$

combining (2) and (7) yields

$J = R, \tag 8$

and we have shown that no invertible element is contained in a *proper* ideal, that is one which is not the whole of $R$.

If $x$ is *not* invertible, we may consider the principal ideal

$xR = \{xy, \; y \in R \}; \tag 9$

note that

$1 \notin xR, \tag{10}$

lest

$\exists z \in R, \; xz = 1, \tag{11}$

i.e.,

$z = x^{-1}, \tag{12}$

in contradiction to the assumption that $x$ has no inverse.  In light of (10), $xR$ is a proper ideal, hence there exists a maximal ideal

$M \subsetneq R \tag{13}$

with

$x= x \cdot 1 \in xR \subset M \subsetneq R, \tag{14}$

and since every maximal ideal is prime, we see that $x$ is contained in some prime ideal.