# Commutative ring without 1. A non invertible nonzero element inside a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra

[An element not belong to any proper prime ideal in given commutative ring with 1.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4298797/an-element-not-belong-to-any-proper-prime-ideal-in-given-commutative-ring-with-1?noredirect=1#comment8952410_4298797)

It was my question with 1 and we can find a proper prime ideal contains every noninvertible element if we have 1.

$i)$**So I am trying to construct a commutative ring without 1. Such that if I have non invertible and not $0$ element it should be inside some prime ideal**.

or $ii)$ **If not can we construct counter example**. I tried $p\mathbb Z$ to show some counter example since we have decomposition for each element any element is in one of the prime ideal.

Also for the positive direction we can find a prime ideal consisting non invertible element if we have 1, if we remove 1 the teorem about every proper ideal being inside a maximal ideal vanishes.

---

**Edit:** Since I was not sure about the statement or counter example it was a bit confusing.

**Question was:** Is every non-invertible element of a commutative ring without 1, is inside one of proper prime ideals.

**Counterexample is** $2\mathbb Z$ and consider $2$ which is non invertible and is not inside any prime ideal.

Comment: or is it true also for just commutative rings without 1 that every nontrivial non invertible element is contained in some prime ideal?

Comment: Not entirely clear on your goal.  How is $R = 2\Bbb{Z}$ not a resolutions for your question?  $2$ is a non-invertible nonzero element, but any ideal containing $2$ is all of $R$, so is not a prime ideal.

Comment: In a ring without $1$ it doesn't even make sense to talk about "invertible elements". So if your ring does not have a one, then **every** element is "non-invertible". So is what you want is a commutative ring (without 1) in which every element is contained in a prime ideal?

Comment: @EricTowers: That was my reading originally; I think he wants an example of a ring without 1 in which every element *is* contained in a prime ideal. Of course there are lots of rings without $1$ in which there are elements not contained in a prime ideal (and even where there are no prime ideals at all, hence no element is contained in one).

Comment: I want a commutative ring A without 1. Such that $Spec(A)\neq \emptyset$ and an element $f\in A$ such that $f$ is not element of any prime ideal and $f$ is not invertible.

Comment: ... so the only thing lacking from my example is that $6\Bbb{Z}$ is prime in $R$... ? ...

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry actually this problem is very very simplification of another one so my head got confused.   Yes we have $2\in 2\mathbb Z$ such that $2$ is not in any prime ideal, and is not invertible. :) thank you Eric Towers and Artugo Magidin

Comment: Can we have the other way around. Such that nonzero element $f\in A$ where $A$ is commutative ring without 1 such that this element inside every proper prime ideal?

Comment: What you describe in your comment above and what you write in your post are two completely different problems. Your post asks for a commutative ring without 1 in which *any* element is in a prime ideal. Your comment asks for a commutative ring without one which has at least one prime ideal in which there is at least one element which is not in any prime ideal. You already have an example of the latter. And you should clean up your post which, again, *is asking a completely different question*.

Comment: And your final comment asks **yet another**, *different* question. Not only should a post ask only one question, not only should you not change the question in the comments, your post should ask what you actually want to ask.

Comment: Okay I am asking this in new post. And I am going to edit the question above.

Comment: And why do you keep talking about "noninvertible elements" in rings without $1$? The definition of "invertible" is that $a$ is invertible if and obnly if there exists a $b$ such that $ab=ba=1_R$. How can you even define invertible without a $1$? If there is no $1$, "invertible" is nonsense; there are no such things as inverses in the absence of an identity.

Comment: You are right !